# Class confusion containing pandas concat

Tags: python, pandas

when i use this class i dont get the transformed dataframe
but the old one
the class instance does not tansfrom the dataframe given as a parameter

```
class DataPreparation:
    
    def __init__(
        self,
        df_train: pd.DataFrame,
        df_test: pd.DataFrame
    ):
        self.df_train = df_train
        self.df_test = df_test
        self.add_embarked()
       

    def add_embarked(self):
        all_embarked = pd.concat([self.df_train.Embarked, self.df_test.Embarked])
        most_commont_value_emb= all_embarked.mode()[0] 
        self.df_train.Embarked.fillna(most_commont_value_emb,  inplace=True) 
        self.df_test.Embarked.fillna(most_commont_value_emb,  inplace=True)
        self.onehotencoder_labels("Embarked")
          
    def onehotencoder_labels(self, column: str):
        one_hot_encoder_train = pd.get_dummies(self.df_train[column])
        one_hot_encoder_test = pd.get_dummies(self.df_test[column])
        self.df_train = pd.concat([self.df_train, one_hot_encoder_train], axis=1)
        self.df_test = pd.concat([self.df_test, one_hot_encoder_test], axis=1)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out [ask] for tips like how to write a good title.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.